# Derivative of $Y \mapsto Y^T Y$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is this derivative done correctly? I've did not find the solution in the matrix cookbook, but followed the similar examples:

$$\frac{\delta Y^TY}{\delta Y} =  ?$$

$$X=Y^TY$$

$$\delta X=(\delta Y^T)Y + Y^T(\delta Y)$$

$$\mathrm{vec}(\delta X)=\mathrm{vec}(\delta Y^TY) + \mathrm{vec}(Y^T\delta Y)$$

$$\mathrm{vec}(\delta X)=(I\otimes Y)\,\mathrm{vec}(\delta Y^T) + (I \otimes Y^T)\,\mathrm{vec}(\delta Y)$$

$$\frac{\delta X}{\delta Y} =  2(I \otimes Y^T)$$

Comment: You need a 4-dimensional matrix to store all the partial derivatives.

Comment: For every entry, we use derivative with respect to matrix, isn't this $I \otimes Y^T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have computed is really $\frac{\delta \operatorname{vec}(Y^TY)}{\delta \operatorname{vec}(Y)}$; I will assume this is what you're really after. I will also assume that you are using the [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) vectorization operator. To correct your mistake, we have the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\delta\operatorname{vec}(Y^TY)
&=\operatorname{vec}(\delta Y^TY) + \operatorname{vec}(Y^T\delta Y)
\\ 
&= (Y^T \otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(\delta Y^T) + (I \otimes Y^T)\operatorname{vec}(\delta Y)
\\ &= 
(Y^T \otimes I)K\operatorname{vec}(\delta Y) + (I \otimes Y^T )\operatorname{vec}(\delta Y)
\\ &= 
[(Y^T \otimes I)K + (I \otimes Y^T)]\operatorname{vec}(\delta Y),
\end{align}
$$
where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) of the correct size. With that, we find that
$$
\frac{\delta \operatorname{vec}(Y^TY)}{\delta \operatorname{vec}(Y)}= (Y^T \otimes I)K + (I \otimes Y^T).
$$

Comment: Ahh, I see, I too eagerly skipped a step when using the Kronecker product. Is there any difference in result between $\frac{\delta \operatorname{vec}(Y^TY)}{\delta \operatorname{vec}(Y)}$ and $\frac{\delta (Y^TY)}{\delta Y}$? As I understand it should be the same solution.

Comment: @Engineeringbridges It ultimately depends on the definitions that are common for the context in which you are doing these calculations. In the context of [tensor calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus), the derivative of a function with matrix inputs and matrix outputs should be a $4$-dimensional array rather than a matrix. So the solutions convey the same information, but they're of distinct "data types".

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$If you absolutely need the tensor-valued gradient, then you have several options.

Perhaps the simplest approach is to take Ben Grossmann's matrix-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
G_{\a\b} &= \grad{x_\a}{y_\b} \quad\iff\quad
G &= \grad{x}{y} &= \grad{\vec{X}}{\vec{Y}} \\
}$$
and reverse the Kronecker-vec indexing
$$\eqalign{
x &\in {\mathbb R}^{n^2\times\o} \implies
X \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n} \\
x_{\a} &= X_{ij} \\
\a &= i+(j-1)\,n \\
i &= \o+(\a-1)\,{\rm mod}\,n \\
j &= \o+(\a-1)\,{\rm div}\,n \\
\\
y &\in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times\o} \implies
Y \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \\
y_{\b} &= Y_{k\ell} \\
\b &= k+(\ell-1)\,m \\
k &= \o+(\b-1)\,{\rm mod}\,m \\
\ell &= \o+(\b-1)\,{\rm div}\,m \\
}$$
to recover the tensor-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
G &\in {\mathbb R}^{n^2\times mn}
 \implies \Gamma\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n\times m\times n} \\
G_{\a\b} &= \Gamma_{ijk\ell} = \grad{X_{ij}}{Y_{k\ell}} \\
}$$